# What is the best way to use python code from Scala (or Java)?

Tags: java, python, scala, jython

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Python Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119696/java-python-integration)

There is some code written in Python and I need to use it from Scala. The code uses some native C. Is it possible to use this from Scala or Java without having to rewrite much?

I intend to use the code as a black-box without understanding, so I prefer not to look into it but rather to somehow generate a jar that I can import in my code.

Comment: There are tons of similar questions. E.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1164810/891391 ? Have you try solutions from there?

Comment: None of the solutions suggested above are plug and play. I was hoping that there is a way to simply generate jar from existing python code. The code uses a lot of C bindings.

Comment: It is also frustrating to see search from Google gives mostly the solution of using java _from_ Python. However, I need the other way round.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a duplicate, even if their is no satisfying answer...

Comment: You can have a look on Jep - https://github.com/ninia/jep/wiki/How-Jep-Works. Jep uses JNI and the CPython API to start up the Python interpreter inside the JVM.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try [Jython](http://www.jython.org/)?You directly compile python code to Java classes or call Python code from Java through interface.

Comment: Jython seems to have some issue with C libraries.

Comment: Agree, and it's struggling on catching up features.

Comment: Because Jython does not support many python libraries. Jython won't work with Python modules that use C/C++.