# Use a Ruby or Python library in Java

Tags: java, python, ruby, jruby, jython

I wonder if it is possible to use a Ruby gem in Java with JRuby.
I found a lot of information on how to use Java classes in Ruby (with JRuby), but not for the other way around. What are the steps to use a Ruby library like  [Asciidoctor](http://asciidoctor.org/) in Java? Would it be also possible to use all Python libraries in Java with [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) like [DocUtils](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: I don't know about Ruby, but for Python see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164810/using-python-from-within-java) and others that can be found by googling "use Python library in Java".

Comment: Yes you are right for Python. The linked answer-documents look quite complicated, I will spend more time on this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may check out this link for embedding Ruby into Java. The author also explains how to call a Ruby Gem from Java.

http://javajing.com/2012/06/01/ruby-from-java.html

There are good show notes with a link to the official JRuby doc on how to run Ruby code from Java.

Personally I used only JRuby. So I do not have any idea about how to do it with Jython.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the link. The show notes are indeed very helpful.