# Python Wifi Issue Connect to Mysterious Camera

Tags: python, camera, ffmpeg

I have been working with some drones and robotics projects using arduino and python.  There was a kickstarter project for a neat little hex copter, that hasn't been managed well.

I was lucky, i got my copter and then some time later after some frustrated email exchanges, i finally recieved the camera as well. To this day, their forum has people still complaining. Their maker forum is now down and their wiki hasn't been updated with any specifics on the camera.

http://www.flexbot.cc/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page#Hardware

Their app to accompany the drone still doesn't support the camera module. Not that it'd matter, as their code isn't very well documented or annotated.

https://github.com/HexAirbot

There are some tips on switching the camera on the comments page of their kickstarter campaign.

https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1387330585/hex-a-copter-that-anyone-can-fly/posts/1093716

So, sob story over, i'm stuck with this neat little wifi camera that i am unsure on how to connect to. I know how to switch it on and it does have a micro-usb port on it.

What library in Python could i use to stream an image from this camera given that it is a wifi camera.  If i wanted the video stream as a numpy matrix.

I need to interface with the camera, so i can connect and disconnect.

Then, be able to read images frame by frame with ffmpeg.  I have some python modules that can detect and read from a camera, but how can my code ensure that the camera is connected?

Totally stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are building for the android platform, you will more than likely need to use some sort of java/python driver/interface, unless you just use java.

Here is an article on java/python, and using python from within java.

[Using Python from within Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164810/using-python-from-within-java)

Comment: I don't want to use android. I would like to use Python. And i am curious about the specific libraries to detect and connect to a camera. Any other tips would also be useful.