# Accessing a Python object from Java Code in Jython 2.5

Tags: java, compiler-construction, jython-2.5

I have an application using Jython 2.1.
In the app I was using jythonc to convert the python scripts to java classes and then include these classes in my webapp like any other.
So I was able to assign package name to python scripts and access these classes like any other java class.

Now I plan to migrate to Jython 2.5. Jython 2.5 has removed support for jythonc.
So I tried to use

```
jython -m compileall /path/to/my/python/scripts.
```

When I do that I get all the compiled bytecode files in the same folder. Each of the files have names like myclass$py.class (where my python file is myclass.py).

My questions -

1. First of all can I access these classes in another normal java
   class?
2. If so, what is the class name I should use ? When I use it like new
   myclass() my code does not compile.
3. Is there a way, I can assign / force a package name or class name
   for the generated bytecode with compileall?

Note -

- I need to upgrade to jython 2.5 because I need newer versions of
  python that it supports.
- I would like to stick with pre-compiling the
  python code into bytecode, as I want to do optimizations on the
  bytecode. So the [recommended](http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/JythonAndJavaIntegration.html) object factory method is only a
  last resort. I am assuming the object factory approach will not allow
  me to process the generated bytecode.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can't answer most of your question as I do not use Python, but ... given the generated class name you ***should*** be able to instantiate the Java class as `new myclass().new py();`.

Comment: @Perception Thanks for your help. Does not look like there exists a true solution to my problem. This [SO Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583192/running-jython-bytecode-using-java/15939006#15939006) is the closest I could get to. I took a similar approach to solution, but my python code is much more sophisticated with classes, inheritance et al. So could not get very far. For now I have decided to stick with Jython 2.1 and revisit this later.

Comment: @Anupama any luck working on this? If so, please answer your question :)